# What does $SIG{'ALRM'} do in Perl

Tags: shell, perl, process, signals, alarm

I'm really new to **shell scripting** and **Perl** and trying to convert a **Perl** script to **Python** script.

I came across a the below code snippet which I didn't clearly understand.

```
sub sigalrm_handler
{
  printf (STDOUT "Timeout: Timeout Error Occured.\n");
  kill (1, $proc);
  exit (1);
}

sub main
{
  ...
  ...
    $SIG{'ALRM'} = \&sigalrm_handler;
    alarm ($ARGV[0]);
    shift @ARGV;

    $proc = spawn (@ARGV);
    wait;
    exit ($?);
  ...
  ...
}
main ()
```

What is this `$SIG{'ALRM'}` command going to do? Is it some kind of special keyword in Python.

I have seen lots of sources where `$SIGALRM` is being used but didn't find any source where they mentioned why it is being used like `$SIGALRM` only why not other name.

What does this `$SIG{'ALRM'}`'s value going to be after that assignment?

Can anyone help me understand this code?

Comment: Perl's built-in alarm/$SIG{ALRM} functionality.

This function, and its associated signal handler, allow you to arrange for your program to receive a SIGALRM signal, which you can then catch and deal with appropriately. An usefull example here https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/weblinux2/modperl/ch06_10.htm

Answer (score 7):

The `%SIG` hash sets up signal handlers for Unix signals. The signal handlers will be called when the kernel sends a signal to the Perl process.

The [alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) function instructs the kernel to send a signal after *n* seconds. The `$SIG{ALRM}` handler will then be invoked and do its thing.

In your specific case, the signal handler will print `Timeout: Timeout Error Occured.` , kill the PID stored in `$proc` and then exit the program.

A Python equivalent might be [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) or [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) for Python 3.

Comment: Is there any Pythonic equivalent to do the same task ?

Comment: Have you tried Google? Googling for `python signal handler` gives me https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html - what is problematic with that library?

Comment: Also, if porting programs from one programming language to another, it would be good to know at least one of them. You don't seem to know either Perl or Python, so maybe ask one of your colleagues for help.

Comment: @anudeep The pythonic way to handle task timeouts is with [async/await](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html), but if you don't know them, just use `signal`.

Comment: Considering the that there is another function `spawn`, what is the following thing going to do?

`$SIG{'ALRM'} = \&sigalrm_handler;

alarm 50;

shift @ARGV;

$proc = spawn (@ARGV);

wait;

exit ($?);`

It is going to wait for 50 seconds for what? What is it expecting to happen from that code which blows the alarm? Updated code in the question.

Comment: Maybe now is a good time to learn about the alarm() syscall - http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html ? I already linked you to it, so maybe read the link in my answer and ask a new question about how alarm() can be used in conjunction with some `spawn()` subroutine you don't declare?